# Using native plugin with callbacks in Unity editor (OS X)

Tags: macos, mono, interop, unity-game-engine

I have a native plugin that has callbacks back to the C# code. This is how the callbacks are setup:

C# Side (Unity):

```
public delegate void Callback(int value);

[DllImport("NativePlugin")]
public static extern void setup_callback(Callback callback);

[MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(Callback))]
private static void OnCallback(int value)
{
    Debug.Log("Callback called with value: " + value);
}

void Start()
{
    setup_callback(OnCallback);
}
```

The Objective-C side (with C wrapper so you'd be able to call it from C#):

```
typedef void(*Callback)(int);

Callback _callback = NULL;

void setup_callback(Callback callback)
{
    _callback = callback;
}

void on_something_happened(int value)
{
    if(_callback)
        _callback(value);
}
```

Now, most of the time the above code works ok, and I receive the correct values in Unity. But sometimes when I make changes to any one of my C# scripts, Unity crashes with this:

```
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000ffffffa9
Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
```

Looking at Unity's Editor logs I found out that when I make changes to a C# script it recompiles Assembly-CSharp.dll and reloads it togheter with some other C# assemblies. So that made me think that this might cause the pointer saved in the native plugin to now point to an invalid address (because Assembly-CSharp.dll is now probably in a different address space). Note that it does not happen every time the dll gets reloaded, is it possible that it gets reloaded to the exact same address space sometimes?

Can I get an event from Unity when the editor reloads the DLL and then re-register the callbacks (assuming that this is the real problem)? Is this even the correct way to setup a callback from native code?

Comment: Hello, I believe that you are doing everything right. This is the way to call a created plugin. However the "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" could  be an uncaught null pointer exception. I suggest you to try debugging your plugin. I know that is really hard task but is all you can do... Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: @Cabrra What is the best way to debug my plugin? I mean, it works well when running it's code as a standalone outside Unity. Is there a way to debug Unity editor?

Comment: Hello again. There is a way to debug the plugin. All you have to do is print the data within the plugin to console using the debug log. I've personally done that in iOs... but is a pain calling the toast messages within android.

Comment: @Cabrra First of all, thanks for your help! I'm trying to debug the native plugin by using NSLog, but I cannot find the output. Is there any log file created by Unity which stores this output?

Comment: I believe that you can stream everything using Debug.Log(string). However I am not sure... Sorry